# Is it possible to only capture Inserts and Updates in snowflake streams

Tags: stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created snowflake stream on table TEST1 to capture change in the data in TEST1 table as below. I only want Inserts and Updates to be captured in STREAM_TEST, so that when I delete records from TEST1, it shouldn't get captured in STREAM_TEST. Is there a way to do that?

```
create or replace stream STREAM_TEST
on table TEST1
APPEND_ONLY = FALSE
comment = 'stream on stage table';
```

Comment: You need to use APPEND=TRUE to avoid deletes; however, deletes are captured with updates (it will record 1 insert and 1 delete, with APPEND=FALSE)

Comment: No need to limit how the stream operates.  You want your stream to be a delta, and if it captures deletes, that's fine.  Just don't apply the deletes to your downstream table in your `MERGE`.  When you execute a DML against that stream, it will clear everything to that point in time, so having deletes in there shouldn't hurt your process at all.